# Converter string separada por virgula em json

Tags: javascript

Tenho a função:

```
$data ={
$G,3,"027",8,"sao paulo"
$H,3,"027",5,"curitiba"
$SP,3,"027",5,"brasilia",62312

}

          var dados = data.split(",");
          var json = [];
          var toSplit = dados.split(",");
          for (var i = 0; i < toSplit.length; i++) {
              json.push({
                      value : toSplit[0],
                      dados:[{
                        info: toSplit[i],
                      }]
             });
           }
```

O problema é que não retorna da forma correta, o esperado seria:

```
{ "$G": { "0": 3, "1": "027", "2": 8, "3": "sao paulo"

}, "$H": { "0": 3, "1": "027", "2": 5, "3": "curitiba"

}, "$SP": { "0": 3, "1": "027", "2": 5, "3": "brasilia", "4": 62312 } }
```

Gostaria de saber onde estou errando..

tks

Comment: Oi! Não está claro onde começa e acaba a string... podes clarificar de onde vem `data`? os `{}` fazem parte da string?

Comment: Creio que aqui `dados.split(",")` vai dá erro por fazer `split` numa array.

Comment: eu receno linha a  linha desta forma

$G,3,"027",8,"sao paulo" /n
$H,3,"027",5,"curitiba" /n
$SP,3,"027",5,"brasilia",62312 /n